# Save and update json data to django models

Tags: django, json, django-models

I have a simple model Class

```
class Talk(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=500)
    title = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

and I connect to oembed api to get data from the url submitted

```
def get_oembed_info(self):
    params = {'url': self.url, 'format': 'json'}
    fetch_url =  'http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?%s' % urllib.urlencode(params)
    result = urllib.urlopen(fetch_url).read()
    result = json.loads(result)
    KEYS = ['title', 'type', 'url', 'description', 'provider_url', 'provider_name', 'width', 'height', 'html', 'thumbnail_url', 'author_url']
    for key in KEYS:
    if result.has_key(key):
         setattr(self, key, result[key])

def save(self):
    self.get_oembed_info()
    super(Talk, self).save()
```

It's ok to add a new Talk from Admin but when i try  to update the same talk later nothing changes.

Also is this way a good to get the data and store it in DB.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe nothing changes on future updates because the server response hasn't changed?

Comment: @dokkaebi - This is true, but suppose i want to change the title or ad more description to the model field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you save, you fetch data from the server and overwrite your model fields. You could check whether it's a new object before fetching:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        self.get_oembed_info()
    super(Talk, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks very much dokkaebi, this solution is awesome.